# Creating an URL with javascript and a variable for jQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use timthumb to dynamically resize an image using jQuery ajax:

```
load_link = "/images/timthumb.php&src=" + link + "&h=194&w=263";
    /* /images/timthumb.php&src=http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3631/5836439169_2230db5e6d_m.jpg&h=194&w=263 */

    $.get(load_link, updateLink);

    function updateLink(data) {
        $('#flickr-first-photo').attr('src',data);
    }
```

But I'm getting no response back from the ajax call. Does anyone know if this is even possible with timthumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
load_link = encodeURI("&src=" + link + "&h=194&w=263&marko=1");
$.get('/images/timthumb.php', load_link, updateLink);

function updateLink(data) {
    $('#flickr-first-photo').attr('src',data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

probably because the URL is not valid. Try to use this:

```
load_link = "/images/timthumb.php&src=" + encodeURI(link) + "&h=194&w=263";
```

Comment: That might improve the link coding but still zero response from the php script